# ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor. Eclipse and Fedora 20 via JDBC

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, listener, fedora

I've installed Oracle 11g XE on a Fedora 20 Virtual Machine, configured it and set the enviroment variables (running the `oracle_env.sh`). I've got this error when trying to connect Eclipse with the database via jdbc, using this string  `"jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.88.134:1521:XE"`

I can connect to the database in the Virtual Machine via SQL*Plus (`sqlplus / as sysdba`).

The `$ORACLE_SID` variable is ok (`XE`). I've already tried to stop and start the listener, then startup the database, and use the `alter system register;` command.

Also statically registering the database without success (I cannot asure I did not mistake doing this, so if somebody thinks this could solve my problem I would try again).

Here is the `listener.ora` file:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: 

SID_LIST_LISTENER = 
  (SID_LIST = 
    (SID_DESC = 
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc) 
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe) 
      (PROGRAM = extproc) 
    ) 
  ) 



LISTENER = 
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST = 
    (DESCRIPTION = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE)) 
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.88.134)(PORT = 1521)) 
    ) 
  ) 

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

And the `tnsnames.ora` file:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: 

XE = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.88.134)(PORT = 1521)) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SERVER = DEDICATED) 
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE) 
    ) 
  ) 

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = PLSExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

And `lsnrctl status`:

```
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 31-MAR-2014 01:22:35 

Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved. 

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE))) 
STATUS of the LISTENER 
------------------------ 
Alias                     LISTENER 
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production 
Start Date                30-MAR-2014 22:41:35 
Uptime                    0 days 2 hr. 41 min. 1 sec 
Trace Level               off 
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication 
SNMP                      OFF 
Default Service           XE 
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora 
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/log/diag/tnslsnr/192/listener/alert/log.xml 
Listening Endpoints Summary... 
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE))) 
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.88.134)(PORT=1521))) 
Services Summary... 
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s). 
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service... 
The command completed successfully
```

I'm almost sure that the problem is that the listener doesn't know about the database. The previous command should show, apart from what it already shows, something like

```
Service XE has 1 instance.
Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler for this service
```

... but it doesn't, and I don't know how to solve this.

I'm new at this, mainly at Linux, so I will appreciate every detail in the solutions you suggest.

Comment: Does your virtual machine have more than one IP address, and what does its name (from `uname -n`) resolve to, in `/etc/hosts` and via `dig`? And just to check, can you issue `alter system register` from your SQL*Plus session, then check the `lsnrctl services` output again; and check whether `show parameters local_listener` shows a blank value?

Comment: As far as I know it has only one IP address. I tried the "alter system register" without success, the listener status ramins unchanged.

Comment: I just saw that you'd tried to register, sorry. But what is your machine name (from `uname`), and what does `/etc/hosts` have for that name?

Comment: uname: Linux.

I don't know how to interpretate it, but this is the content of /etc/hosts file:

127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
 
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like your database is trying to register using the wrong IP address to contact the listener. Your listener is configured to listen on 192.168.88.134, but perhaps the DB is assuming localhost (127.0.0.1), or an old IP value if the configuration has ever changed.

By default the database will attempt to register against the server's external host name ([the default when local_listener is blank](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/initparams116.htm)), but you may be getting an unexpected value from that - so what is in `/etc/hosts` for the machine name matters. Whatever has caused that, registration seems to be failing.

You can explicitly tell the DB to register using the actual listener address:

```
alter system set local_listener = '192.168.88.134:1521' scope=memory;
alter system register;
```

If that works and `lsnrctl services` now shows `XE`, then repeat the `set` command with `scope=both` to make it stick on the next DB restart.

Comment: I tried it and now "lsnrctl status" finally shows XE, and JDBC connection works perfectly. Actually, it makes sense because I had to change the IP address where the listener was listening to make it work. It's strange I haven't seen anything about this in my search. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Troubleshooting:

1. remove listener.ora (for this initial setup, you don't need it. make a backup of it)
2. lsnrctl reload

or

add XE to your SID_LIST like:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER = 
  (SID_LIST = 
     (SID_DESC =
       (SID_NAME = XE)
       (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe)
     )    
     (SID_DESC = 
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc) 
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe) 
      (PROGRAM = extproc) 
    ) 
  )
```

lsnrctl reload

check the alert log for messages.

Answer (score 0):

In your listener.ora:

> > (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.88.134)(PORT = 1521))

Usually here by default there is a hostname instead of IP address. Did you do something special so that you have that IP there (192.168.88.134)?