# Connecting to oracle 12c using Oracle Sql developer (remote)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I have been trying to connect to Oracle 12c remotely by using Oracle SQL developer. It shows the below error during connecting to the server :

```
 Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

I do can connect to oracle database on the server, but the problem is regarding to connect to this server (database) remotely

The content of my listener.ora is :

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
(SID_LIST =
(SID_DESC =
  (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
  (ORACLE_HOME = D:\app\ORCLNEWUSER\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1)
  (PROGRAM = extproc)
  (ENVS =  "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:d:\app\ORCLNEWUSER\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")
)
)

LISTENER =
(DESCRIPTION_LIST =
(DESCRIPTION =      
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))     
)
)
```

Comment: Is the listener running? Or a firewall blocking the access?

Comment: Listener is running and Also the firewall is off

Comment: Thanks Alex, I'm new in oracle . 
could you tell me how I can config this file , since I have a server with a valid IP address and I'm trying to connect to this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `listener.ora` says that is only listening on `localhost` (127.0.0.1), so nothing will be able to connect from anywhere except the server; there is nothing listening on port 1521 on the server's external IP address. You can verify that with `lsnrctl status` and `netstat -ano | find "1521"`.

You need to modify the `listener.ora` to listen on your server's hostname, or if that isn't resolvable to the correct IP, the external IP address itself - the 'valid IP address' you're trying to connect to from SQL Developer:

```
LISTENER =
(DESCRIPTION_LIST =
(DESCRIPTION =      
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = my_hostname_or_ip)(PORT = 1521))     
)
)
```

You may also need to check that your database is able to register successfully. I'd verify if it is included in `lsnctrl services` before and after you make that change and restart the listener. If it doesn't appear after the restart, and `alter system register` doesn't make it appear, then you might need to change the `local_listener` database parameter to tell it the address and port it should register against. That's a separate issue really but could follow on from this change; [there's an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22769396/266304) which might help if it does.

Comment: When I change the HOST to the IP of server in (listener.ora file), the listener's service doesn't start

Comment: @Ali - do you get an error on the command line, or anything helpful in the log?

Comment: I forgot to mention which I'm using Windows server 2008 
and the existing host (localhost) is working fine , as you mentioned it only listening on localhost, but when I change it to the IP of server and I try to restart the listener's service it gives me this error : "The listener service on Local computer started and then stopped. some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs"

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this on Windows. Are you sure the IP you used is valid - does `netstat` shows other ports listening on that address? (Or is this perhaps a VM and there's NAT confusing things?)

Comment: Yes , it's valid IP address 
I'm not quiet sure about this server which is running on VM or not ,, but currently I'm using SQL server and I connect to this server only with IP address and it works

Comment: @Ali - so what does the listener log file say? Why does it say it stopped? (Are you sure you didn't delete a bracket or make some other typo when you edited the file?)

Comment: it says : TNS-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00515: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
   64-bit Windows Error: 49: Unknown error

Comment: @Ali - then the IP address is not valid, or you have some other error in the `ADDRESS` line. Check the IP is listed by `ipconfig` and that you can ping it - copying from the file to make sure you didn't mistype it, maybe. Not sure what else to suggest, sorry.

Comment: Thank you so much , you are right the problem was about the IP address, since it was using VM and different IP addresses confused me