# Database remote connection issue

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have installed database 11g on machine A (Windows). And now I need to access that database from machine B (Windows), where my application is placed. I am able to ping B --> A but telnet is not working. Below are a few files for reference.

A few things which I have already tried:

1. Have disabled firewall.
2. Have opened ports using inbound and outbound rules.
3. Have started the services.

listener.ora

```
listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\rajhegde\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora

Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\rajhegde\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\rajhegde\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS =
        (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1522)
      )
      (ADDRESS =
        (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = rajhegde-lap2)(PORT = 1522))
      )
    )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\app\rajhegde
```

tnsnames.ora

```
tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\rajhegde\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora

Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS =
   (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1522)
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS =
        (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1522))
      )
      (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL = 
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS =
      (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1522)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

Output of lsnrctl status

C:\Users\rajhegde>lsnrctl status

```
LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 09-SEP-2015 18:56 :36

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle. All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC8080)))

STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                09-SEP-2015 17:40:03
Uptime                    0 days 1 hr. 16 min. 36 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   C:\app\rajhegde\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora 
Listener Log File         c:\app\rajhegde\diag\tnslsnr\RAJHEGDE-LAP2\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\.\pipe\EXTPROC8080ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=RAJHEGDE-LAP2.oradev.oraclecorp.com)
    (PORT=1522)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Comment: Check if the firewall is not blocking the ports you are trying to access and if the oracle service is running properly (that is listenning on a port for connections).

Comment: You haven't said how you're connecting, but the tags imply SQL Developer, so showing the connection settings you're using would be helpful. Are you trying to telnet to port 1522? Can you also format your question to make it easier to read? But your database isn't registered with the listener, and the IPs in your listener.ora and tnsnames.ora don't match, so you possibly have [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22769396/266304), and need to check/set the `local_listener` parameter? Check what `rajhegde-lap2` resolves to, and compare with that setting, and what you're using to connect.

Comment: Also, please don't [cross-post](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/114576/847)